# android: tabhost in a fragment, w/ fragments as tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am trying to have a tabhost that it contained in a fragment, where the tab content is defined by fragments. okay then,

I started from the [FragmentsTab](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) example from google. this shows how to use fragments as the tab content, but the `TabHost` itself is still hosted in an activity. again, i need the tab host to be hosted in a Fragment.

I took `FragmentsTab` example, and moved the the code in `onCreate()` and moved it to `onCreateView()` in my `Fragment`,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) fragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mTabManager = new TabManager(getActivity(), mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    // TODO: localize
    mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator("File Info"), InfoFragment.class, null);

    return fragmentView;
}
```

when i run, i get this exception,

```
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1343)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:429)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.TabManager.onTabChanged(TabManager.java:116)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:359)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:344)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.TabManager.addTab(TabManager.java:92)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.DetailFragment.onCreateView(DetailFragment.java:46)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:819)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1371)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:429)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.TabManager.onTabChanged(TabManager.java:116)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:359)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:344)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.TabManager.addTab(TabManager.java:92)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at com.zimbra.octopus.android.DetailFragment.onCreateView(DetailFragment.java:46)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:819)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1111)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
05-25 14:42:27.272: E/AndroidRuntime(4701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

looking at the trace, i see `onCreateView()` for `DetailFragment` (the fragment hosting the `TabHost`) call recursively. somehow, the call to `TabManager.addTab()` (again see the FragmentsTab example) is resulting in a recursive call to `DetailFragment.onCreateView()`.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: You aren't trying to embed a fragment within another fragment, are you?

Comment: yes, i am. i guess you are going to tell me that's my problem, correct?

Comment: Yup, the framework doesn't allow you to do this... sorry about that -_-

Comment: From the documentation: "A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't allow you to embed one fragments inside other fragments. Your logcat indicates that you are executing one fragment transaction within another (i.e. recursive entry to executePendingTransactions). It's just not allowed, sorry!

Comment: Nested fragments are now supported. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-ui-tools

This should allow Fragment tab inside of a Fragment tab host, correct?

Answer (score 0):

add this before you setup your TabHost:

```
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), false);
mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
mTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```